# c# press keyboard button from button at gui

Tags: c#, button, keyboard

how to press keyboard by clicking button at gui ?
so when this application is running and  i press button1 from GUI the F1 button at my keyboard pressed to...

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //F1 button at my keyboard pressed...
        }
```

Comment: So you want to inject F1 into the window message pump? What control would receive that keypress? It seems like an XY problem, what are you *actually* trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why do you want to press F1?  Do you not just want to simulate the behaviour of whatever F1 does within the context of your application?

Comment: my problem is at unity (3D)
my object cant transform to another postion by command from udp socket cause udp recieve need create new thread to receive data.
and unity didn't give acces to control object or whatever api unity  method from different thread.
so i just want to create simple way by button press

Comment: So why do you need a key press instead of just going off the button click? Or do you need this F1 sent to a *different* application?

Comment: cause this application will run on another computer....
i want to control object at my unity project from another compter.
since udp recieve need create new thread to receive data, and unity don't give acces control from another thread so i canto control my object from my socket instead..
so i just want to create simple way by button press.

Comment: So just to be clear, you want this button to press the F1 key *on a different computer*? You are going to have to do the sockets anyways, why not just marshal the command onto the unity thread? Just for the record, getting a button press to another app like that is anything but "Simple".

Comment: Not like that....
my control object MUST in my GUI application
"You are going to have to do the sockets anyways"
please read my comment before

Comment: what? That statement made no sense at all.

Comment: back to topic off my question

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //F1 or another button at my keyboard pressed...
        }

Comment: I don't think you understand what I am saying. To fulfill your requirements, you will need to send a message to a process on the computer running the Unity app (via some sort of socket). That app is (a) part of the Unity app, and so needs to marshal the message onto the UI thread, as you have noted, or (b) a separate application, and so needs to inject the F1 WM_KEY message into the Unity message pump, which while possible, will require a great deal of work with the Win32 API. The former is likely *much* easier. Are you asking how to do the latter?

Comment: Unity has the concept of network game sessions - have you looked into that: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NetworkReferenceGuide.html. I'd tend to agree with BradleyDotNET - my approach would be to have some sort of publicly advertised method on the client, then execute it from another machine on the network via the game session. Specifically, Unity offers RPC (Remote Procedure Calls) which could be used to trigger a remote method - http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/net-RPCDetails.html